# Can't Install vmware-view-client from partner repo in Saucy

Tags: 13.10, vmware

I'm having trouble installing a vmware-view-client from the partner repo. I think I've troubleshooted it down to needing to install libudev0, but only libudev1 is available. I was wondering if anyone could think of a workaround to get libudev0 installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a guide [here](http://blog.mbentley.net/2013/05/vmware-view-client-1-7-2-0-on-ubuntu-13-04-i386amd64/) on how ot get it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using synaptic.  If Synaptic Package Manager is not installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once installed open synaptic from Dash, and search for vmware-view-client.  Once found, right click on it, and choose Mark for Installation.  That will take care of installing all the necessary dependencies.  See image below.

[image]

Once done, just click on the green check mark to apply the changes.

To download [libudev0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libudev0)

Comment: Yeah, I was installing it with synaptic. It says it cannot resolve that dependency.